# Convert string to columns with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the below table, just one column and one raw, and I want to convert the string separated by commas in columns.
It's an exercise to be completed

table

| Column 1 |
| --- |
| A, B,C, D |

Output

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

How could you convert the string to columns?

Comment: Storing values as CSV is veri bad db design. You should think about a redesign of your db

Comment: Please tag the DBMS you use.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to know why tagging is important.

Comment: Storing multiple values in a single column isn't just "bad design", it violates [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). That means your data is not relational; relational commands aren't going to work on it, and there is little point in using SQL. Either convert your data to columns, or use a CSV parser on it instead of SQL.

Comment: How would you move data from rows to columns separated by comma?

Answer (score 1):

Just an option using JSON

```
Select A.[YourColumn]
       ,Pos1 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
       ,Pos2 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
       ,Pos3 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')
       ,Pos4 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[3]')
       ,Pos5 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[4]')
       ,Pos6 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[5]')
       ,Pos7 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[6]')
 From  YourTable A
Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(string_escape([YourColumn],'json'),',','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)
Results
```

Answer (score 1):

As an exercise, you could do this as follows - I'm not totally sure your desired results are what you actually want?

If you actually want the delimited values as values in separate columns, and your data is as shown, you could use *parsename* as follows:

```
with sampledata as (
  select 'A, B, C, D' col1
)
select ParseName(c,4) col1, ParseName(c,3) col2, ParseName(c,2) col3, ParseName(c,1) col4
from sampledata
cross apply (select Replace(col1, ', ', '.'))x(c);
```

[image]

If you *do* actually want the delimited values to be used as column names with static data, you can adapt it with some dynamic-sql:

```
declare @sql NVarchar(max);

with sampledata as (
  select 'A, B, C, D' col1
)
select @sql = Concat (
  'select 1 ', QuoteName('column ' + ParseName(c,4)),
       ', 1 ', QuoteName('column ' + ParseName(c,3)),
       ', 1 ', QuoteName('column ' + ParseName(c,2)),
       ', 1 ', QuoteName('column ' + ParseName(c,1))
)
from sampledata
cross apply (select Replace(col1, ', ', '.'))x(c);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Column1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 

);
INSERT INTO mytable
(Column1) VALUES 
('A,B,C,D');
```

use `STRING_SPLIT`,`CROSS APPLY`,`Pivot` and `Subquery` as follows

```
select *
from 
(
select concat('Column ',value) name,1 value1 from mytable
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Column1, ',') 
) src
pivot
(
  max(value1)
  for name in ([Column A], [Column B], [Column C],[Column D])
) piv;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/laN4UNtJ)